# How do i print somthing when a function DOES NOT returns a cetain thing

Tags: python, function, if-statement

```
def collideY(player, object):
    if man.x <= object.x + object.width and man.x + man.width >= object.x: # Checks if  the player is inside the bounderies of a list of objects
        return "F"

cY = collideY(Player, object)
if not cY == "F":
    print("Not F")
```

This prints "not F" all the time and i want it to print only when F is not returned
P.S This is my entire code if you want to see it
This is a recreation of Mario. The game runs well but i am having trouble adding gravity when the player gets off a platform. What i need to do is detect when the player (man) is not in the x range of the objects. i ahve a function called CollisionY() which already checks if the player is in the x range of the objects(all this is located in the while loop) I can make the function return a variable when it detects the man in the x range but for some reason i cannot get it to detect when it is not in the objects x range

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

pygame.init()

# Screen Setup
Screen_Height = 600
Screen_Width = 800
Screen_Size = (Screen_Width, Screen_Height)
win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Mario")

# Sprites for Mario
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('mario_move0.png'), pygame.image.load('mario_move1.png'),
             pygame.image.load('mario_move2.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('mario_move02.png'), pygame.image.load('mario_move12.png'),
            pygame.image.load('mario_move22.png')]

char = pygame.image.load('mario.png')
char2 = pygame.image.load('mario2.png')
jumping = pygame.image.load("mario_jump.png")
jumping2 = pygame.image.load("mario_jump2.png")

#Setup Background
bg = pygame.image.load('level_1.png')
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (9000, 600)).convert()
bgWidth, bgHeight = bg.get_rect().size

#Map sprites
spritesheet = pygame.image.load("tile_set.png")
character = Surface((15, 16), pygame.SRCALPHA)
character.blit(spritesheet, (-17, 0))
character = pygame.transform.scale(character, (44, 44))
brick1 = character




clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height ):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 1
        self.isJump = False
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.standing = True
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.starting = True
        self.runCount = 0
        self.jumping = 0
        self.currenty = 410
        self.done = True
        self.ableJump = False
        self.scroll = 0
        self.x3 = 0
        self.fall = False
        self.rightStop = False
        self.leftStop = False
        self.grav = .4
    def draw(self, win):

        if self.walkCount + .5 >= 3:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if self.runCount >= 12:
            self.runCount = 12

        if self.left and not self.isJump and not self.standing and not self.fall:
            win.blit(walkLeft[self.walkCount], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
            if self.runCount < 12:
                self.runCount += 1

        elif self.right and not self.isJump and not self.standing and not self.fall:
            win.blit(walkRight[self.walkCount], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
            if self.runCount < 12:
                self.runCount += 1

        if self.standing and self.right and not self.isJump or self.starting and not self.fall:
            win.blit(char, (self.x, self.y))

        elif self.standing and self.left and not self.isJump and not self.fall:
            win.blit(char2, (self.x, self.y))

        elif self.isJump or self.fall:
            if self.right:
                win.blit(jumping, (self.x, self.y))

            elif self.left:
                 win.blit(jumping2, (self.x, self.y))

class Object(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, type=""):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.type = type # OPTIONAL

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 5)

    def draw_brick(self, win):
        win.blit(brick1,(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

def collideY(player, object):
    if man.x <= object.x + object.width and man.x + man.width >= object.x: # Top check
        if man.y <= object.y + object.height and man.y + man.height >= object.y + object.height:
            return "D"
        elif man.y <= object.y and man.y + man.height >= object.y:
            return "U"
    else:
        return "F"

    return False

def collideX(player, object):
    if man.x + man.width >= object.x and man.x <= object.x: # Left side collision
        if man.y + man.height > object.y and man.y < object.y + object.height:
            return "L"

    elif man.x <= object.x + object.width and man.x + man.width >= object.x + object.width: # right side collision
        if man.y + man.height > object.y and man.y < object.y + object.height:
            return "R"

def right():
    # Right movement
    if not keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            if man.x == 400 and not man.fall and man.x3 < 8572:
                man.scroll -= (man.vel * man.runCount) * 1.5
            else:
                man.x += (man.vel * man.runCount) * 1.5
        elif man.x == 400 and not man.fall and man.x3 < 8572:
            man.scroll -= man.vel * man.runCount
        else:
            man.x += man.vel * man.runCount

        if man.x >= 400 and man.x3 < 8572:
            man.x = 400

        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.standing = False
        man.starting = False

def left():
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        man.x -= (man.vel * man.runCount) * 1.5
    else:
        man.x -= man.vel * man.runCount
    man.left = True
    man.right = False
    man.standing = False
    man.starting = False

def standing():
    man.standing = True
    man.done = True
    man.isJump2 = False
    man.walkCount = 0
    man.runCount = 0
    if man.right or man.left:
        if not man.isJump:
            man.alex = 0

def redrawGameWindow():

    man.draw(win)
    for o in objs:
        o.draw(win)
    for o in objs_1:
        o.draw_brick(win)
    pygame.display.update()
    win.blit(bg, (man.scroll, 0))
# mainloop
man = player(200, 505, 32, 32)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    objs = [  # Solid Blocks
            Object(man.scroll + 1196, 451, 71, 100),
            Object(man.scroll + 1622, 410, 71, 135),
            Object(man.scroll + 1961, 368, 71, 185),
            Object(man.scroll + 2427, 368, 71, 185),

            Object(man.scroll + 5690, 490, 167, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 5734, 449, 123, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 5775, 408, 80, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 5817, 365, 40, 40),

            Object(man.scroll + 5942, 490, 167, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 5942, 449, 125, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 5942, 408, 80, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 5943, 365, 40, 40),

            Object(man.scroll + 6287, 490, 207, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 6331, 449, 163, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 6372, 408, 120, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 6414, 365, 80, 40),

            Object(man.scroll + 6579, 490, 167, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 6579, 449, 125, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 6579, 408, 80, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 6579, 365, 40, 40),

            Object(man.scroll + 6928, 451, 71, 100),
            Object(man.scroll + 7607, 451, 73, 100),

            Object(man.scroll + 7680, 492, 382, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 7724, 452, 341, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 7765, 410, 299, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 7808, 366, 256, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 7851, 324, 214, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 7893, 281, 172, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 7934, 238, 130, 40),
            Object(man.scroll + 7978, 194, 88, 40),

            Object(man.scroll + 8407, 491, 40, 40),
           ]

    objs_1 = [
                Object(man.scroll + 850, 381, 44, 44),
                Object(man.scroll + 938, 381, 44, 44),
                Object(man.scroll + 1026, 381, 44, 44),

             ]

# Jump Height
    if man.standing or man.left or man.right:
        if not man.isJump:
            man.currenty = man.y
    jumpHeight = man.currenty - man.y
    jumpHeight = int(jumpHeight)

# Collisions / interactions for solid blocks
    for obj in objs:
        cX = collideX(man, obj)
        cY = collideY(man, obj)
        if man.isJump :
            if cY == "U":
                print("Up")
                man.standing = True
                man.isJump = False
                man.ableJump = True
                man.y = obj.y - man.height
            elif cY == "D":
                print("Down")
                man.y = obj.y + obj.height + 1
            elif cX == "R" and cY == False:
                print("Right")
                man.x = obj.x + obj.width + 1
            elif cX == "L" and cY == False:
                print("Left")
                man.x = obj.x - man.width - 1
        else:
            if cX == "R":
                print("Right")
                man.x = obj.x + obj.width + 1
            elif cX == "L":
                print("Left")
                man.x = obj.x - man.width - 1

# Collision / interactions with brick1
    for obj in objs_1:
        cX = collideX(man, obj)
        cY = collideY(man, obj)
        if man.isJump :
            if cY == "U":
                print("Up")
                man.standing = True
                man.isJump = False
                man.ableJump = True
                man.y = obj.y - man.height
            elif cY == "D":
                print("Down")
                if man.y < obj.y + obj.height:
                    man.y = obj.y + obj.height
                man.ableJump = False
            elif cX == "R" and cY == False:
                print("Right")
                man.x = obj.x + obj.width + 1
            elif cX == "L" and cY == False:
                print("Left")
                man.x = obj.x - man.width - 1
        elif not man.isJump:
            if cX == "R":
                print("Right")
                man.x = obj.x + obj.width + 1
            elif cX == "L":
                print("Left")
                man.x = obj.x - man.width - 1
        if not cY == "F":
            print("00")
        #else:
            #print("69")

# X.3 is the equivalent x cordinate on the map
    man.x3 = -1 * man.scroll + man.x

# Able to Quit without crashing
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

# Defies the movement keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

# Left movement
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > 4 and not man.leftStop:
        left()

# Right movement
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x3 < 8956 and not man.rightStop:
        right()

    elif not man.isJump:
        standing()

# Jump mechanics
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and man.ableJump:
        if jumpHeight < 200:
            man.isJump = True
            man.runCount = 10
            man.jumpCount = 6

        else:
            man.ableJump = False
    elif man.isJump:
        man.ableJump = False

    if man.isJump:
        if man.jumpCount >= -8:
            neg = 1
            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            man.jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            man.jumpCount = -8
        man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg



# Ground floor
    if man.y >= 505:
        if man.x3 > 2927 and man.x3 < 2985 or man.x3 > 3649 and man.x3 < 3750 or man.x3 > 6492 and man.x3 < 6552:
            man.fall = True
            man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.09 * -1
        elif not man.fall:
            man.y = 505
            man.isJump = False
            man.ableJump = True

    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: "i want it to print only when F is not returned"... What makes you think this is not the case?

Comment: typo the code has not typos in it this is an example I made up. so what happens is that it always prints for some reason and i dont understand why

Comment: Functions _always_ return a value.  In your function, when the `if` statement is false, the function returns `None` by default.  `None` is not equal to `F`, so it prints "Not F".

Comment: Ohhhh ok i understand is there a way to make so when it is not returning F to print something?

Comment: seems like you just need to change `cY = collideY(player, object)` to `cY = collideY(player, man)`

Comment: on the code it is man and not Player but for sakes of not putting all the code i just put that as the example but that is not the problem I'm having my code works fine

Comment: still doesn't change anything...

Comment: cannot reproduce, does not print "Not F" https://repl.it/@downshift/TautTriangularConcentrate

Comment: Yes i understand but when i apply this to my code it does it makes no sense to me why

Answer (score 0):

#### couple of issues

1. The problem is, your collideY function is never returning "F" because you are not passing it an instance of a class. Instead, you are passing it the class itself.
2. `object` is a python internal class. Don't name a variable `object`.

**try changing the collideY method to this**

```py
def collideY(man, bounds):
    if man.x <= bounds.x + bounds.width and man.x + man.width >= bounds.x: # Checks if  the player is inside the bounderies of a list of objects
        return "F"
```

and call the function like this `collideY(man, bounds)`

You are passing a class instance instead you should pass an object instance like `man` if you want it to work.

Comment: what i need to figure out now is how to make it so it prints something when its not returning F

Comment: That part of your code is correct. I believe problem is in `collideY` function. maybe try printing what your collideY function to debug.

Comment: It'll be helpful if you can show Player class (hiding any sensitive code ofcourse) and where that `man` variable is coming from

Comment: @VenomStrike what do you mean child of player class? Is it an object or is it an attribute. if it is object, you should pass man (object) to the method not the class instance.

Comment: class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height ):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height                                                                                 man = player(200, 505, 32, 32)

Comment: So im making  aplatformer game and im almost doen all i need to do isa add gravity whne the player gets off a platform(my code is complicated so i cant turn it off whne im on the platform) so i need to check when the player is not on in the x range if the blocks to add gravity

Comment: Just change `collideX(player,object):` and `collideY(player,object):` to `collideX(man,obj):` and `collideY(man,obj):` respectively and inside these two functions, replace `object` with `obj` and see if that solves your problem

Comment: no, it did not fix it. I don't think its any of that

Comment: try a debugging step to see if your intended data is reaching ```print(man.x,man.y,man.width,man.height,bounds.x,bounds.y,bounds.height,bounds.width)```

Comment: I think its here where the problem is (I cut the other code that is not needed)                                                                                                                            
    for obj in objs_1:
        cX = collideX(man, obj)
        cY = collideY(man, obj)
        if not cY == "F":  # Here it checks when the player is in the x range 
            print("00")      # Here i can see this works
        else:   # Here im trying to check when they player is not in the x range
            print("11") # But this prints when im in the range and outside

Comment: Everything works it can detect when the player in inside the x range of the objects/ platforms an di can get it to print somthing when it is and not print it whenits not, but i need the complete opposite. i need to print somthing when the player is not in the x range. i put an else statment to do the opposite but it prints all the time while the player is in the x range or not